# How to send video data and object detection bounding box separately in server , then play them together

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

[image]

We have set up an object detection system on our computer where we can detect object from video file. our requirement is to  send this video file and object detection bounding box in JSON format in the server. then in the server we will read this video file (mp4)  with object detection bounding box( in JSON format) and play them together. How to solve this kinds of problem, any open source example for that?